# Only ImportError when running file directly

Tags: python, linux, python-import, importerror, absolute-path

I've got a system built in Python in which I now want to run some functions periodically with a regular cron. So I made a file which starts off like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from app.models import User
```

When I import the file from the interactive Python command line I there are no problems:

```
>>> from app.crons import scrapeChannels
>>>
```

But when I run the file directly from the terminal I get the ImportError:

```
$ /home/kramer65/app/crons/scrapeChannels.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kramer65/app/crons/scrapeChannels.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app.models import User
ImportError: No module named app.models
```

Now I assume this has something to do with the fact that `app.models` not in the sys.path is, but from this point I'm kinda lost. Am I right in my assumption? And how can I solve this issue?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: You cannot run a script *inside* a package and hope that Python picks up the whole package, no. Put scripts **outside** of the `app` package, and / or add `/home/kramer65` to the `PYTHONPATH` (either via the environment variable or via `sys.path` manipulation in Python).

Comment: why are you importing `app.models` in the file but testing `app.crons` at the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you want to run the script from cron as well, the best would be to manually append the parent directory of `app` (which seems to be `/home/kramer65/` to your `sys.path` , before the line `from app.models import User` .

Example -

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/kramer65/')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the directory containing the `app` package to your python path, using [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

```
$ set PYTHONPATH=/home/kramer65
$ /home/kramer65/app/crons/scrapeChannels.py
```